# Tidtcpserver listening on multiports?

Tags: indy, indy10

alright i am trying to understand this approach , lets say i have run 2 servers

Server A is on Ip 1.1.1.1 and port 36663
Server B is on ip 2.2.2.2 and port 54223

i am asking to be able to understand this approach

can i  make clients on server A be able to communicate with clients on Server B ?
as example a client is connecting on Server A and want to send some data to a client who connecting to server B is this can be done using indy tcp server ?

if the answer is yes an example will be much helpful to fully understand this approach .

i have 2 servers on different machine

1 machine have some slow network issue and the other have good network.

the logic here is when the client to serverA that takes more than 20 seconds to connect, during this  20  seconds try to reconnect to  other server ip and be able to  communicate with the client that already coonnected on serverA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` has a `Bindings` property, which is a collection of IP/Port pairs that the server listens on.  You can have a single `TIdTCPServer` object listening on multiple IP/Port pairs, or you can use multiple `TIdTCPServer` objects listening on different pairs, *on the same machine*.

Either way, the connected clients are stored in the `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` property.

When a client wants to send data to another client, regardless of which server IP/Port it is connected to, all you have to do is iterate through the `Contexts` list of the appropriate `TIdTCPServer` object until you find the `TIdContext` object of the target client, and then you will have access to its `Connection.IOHandler` property.

---

On the other hand, if you have separate `TIdTCPServer` objects running on *different machines*, clients cannot directly communicate with clients on another server.  You would have to establish a connection between the two servers and then you can proxy any client-to-client data through that connection as needed.

Comment: so i only add multi ip and port to the binding , this approach is needed to handle some fail connections as example if server A takes long time to connect then connect to server B and still be able to communicate to server A

Comment: Opening ports does not influence the time it takes to connect to them.  If you open two ports *on the same server machine*, a client could connect to either port, and it should take the same amount of time either way.  Now, if you have *two server machines* and you want them to talk to each other, that is a completely different issue. I suggest you edit your question to clarify your actual situation.